# ASP.NET GridView sorting on a calculated field

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a DataBound GridView.  However I have one column where the value comes from a calculation in the code behind - it is displayed within a TemplateField.

How can a sort my grid based on this calculated value ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your initial returned data into a DATASET or a DATATABLE. Add to the DATATABLE a new column for you calculated field. Walked that data doing the necessary calculation, and putting the result into said calculated field.

Create a new view based on the datatable, and sort the view by the calculated field. Bind the grid to the data view.

```
Dim DT as DataTable 
DT = GetDataTableFromDataBaseMethod()
DT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("CalculatedColumnName"))
For each row as DataRow in DT.Rows
    row("CalculatedColumnName") = PerformCalculations(row)
Next 

Dim view as New DataView 
view.DataTable =dt 
View.Sort = "CalculatedColumnName DESC"

datagrid1.Datasource = view
datagrid1.Databind
```

Or, if possible, perform the calculation in the SQL statement, re:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col1+Col2+Col3 AS LineTotal FROM Table;
```

Comment: There's another way to do that. You can add the Column to `DataTable` as correctly suggested by @Stephen but then, if you need to calculate the new column as an expression using other columns of the `DataTable`, you don't need to loop through all the rows. You can simply use `DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromDataBaseMethod();` and then, as an example, `dt.Columns.Add("CalculatedColumnName", typeof(double), "(FirstValueColumn - SecondValueColumn) * ThirdValueColumn");`. This could be very useful if you can't add directly your expression into the query, that anyway is always the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to populate a datatable instead of binding the grid. Then use a dataview with the sort set to your calculated column, and bind that to the grid in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to consider is adding calculated column to the database table itself.  This has the benefit of returning the calculated column in the same SQL expression that loads the rest of the row, but unfortunately does require changing the database schema.

Comment: Yes, I do this in places where it is worth persisting the data - but this was in a specific placed and I didn't want to change the schema

Answer (score 0):

Note that adding a column to the datatable will mark all rows as updated, so when saving back to the database, it will try to update all records.